# Excel .net component?

Tags: excel

I need an excel component for developing which replace for M$ Excel COM component, because i don't want my client install their excel component on the machine any more, but make sure that it support copy, paste and delete cell direct on the document (grid in asp.net).

(open source, free or commercial)

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 5):

I would 100% recommend [SpreadsheetGear](http://www.spreadsheetgear.com/).  We replaced all of our Excel COM components with their tool about a year ago, and we haven't looked back.  It's got near-Excel API compatibility as well.  In half our projects, it was as easy as changing the references.